# How to use Array and IndexOf together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an array of strings and use indexOf function to check if the text exists on `<td>` or not, if it does I want it to execute else do nothing?
for .e.g One exists on `<td>` so indexOf recognizes that executes
The problem is this code is not working at the moment it was working when I was not using an array.

UPDATES- Thanks that indexOf works fine but the way I have used an array on var str doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<tbody>
 <td><a href='#'>One</a></td>
 <td>No.</td>
</tbody>
```

Jquery

```
var array =  ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
var str = $('td:contains(" + array + ")').text();
if(array.indexOf(str) > -1){
 console.log('Array works');
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Keep in mind that `$('td').text()` will return text content of every td on the page. `"OneNo."` in the case provided.

Comment: The array doesn't seem to work for var str = $('td:contains(" + array + ")').text(); have I used it wrong? I am still learning sorry if the question that i am asking are basic.

Comment: what is the value of str when it hits your if statement?

Comment: You could open the console and check what `'td:contains(" + array + ")'` is. Then open jquery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to check how contains selector works. Passing entire array to the selector wont work.

Comment: It could be anything from an array ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' ....] as the <td></td>value changes that why I am trying to keep it as an array.

Answer (score 1):

You're using it the wrong way around. In this case, you want the `indexOf()` prototype of `Array`, not string, so your logic should be:

```
if( array.indexOf(str) > -1 )
{
  // Do stuff!
}
```

Comment: Actually it is also a  String prototype method

Answer (score 1):

As @BenM specified, the `.indexOf()` method is not used this way.

Maybe this snippet will be of use :

```js
var array =  ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

// iterate over every <td> element found in the page with the .each() function
$('td').each(
    function(){
        if(array.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1){
            console.log('"' + $(this).text() + '" was found in the array');
        }
    }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
             <td><a href='#'>One</a></td>
             <td>No.</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for and it works Thanks again